# How to save loop-generated material to environment in R

Tags: r

I have written a simple loop in R to generate the layout of a 96-well plate using the constant LETTERS.

```
for (alpha in LETTERS[1:8]){
  print(paste(alpha, 1:12, sep=""))
}
```

How can I modify this to save the generated plate map as an environmental variable, ideally a matrix? I would like it to directly create the environmental variable and avoid using the save & read.table combo.

Comment: Somewhat unclear.  Is `t(sapply(LETTERS[1:8], paste0, 1:12))` what you want?

Comment: I think he wants that transposed, t(sapply(LETTERS[1:8], paste0, 1:12))

Comment: Darwin is right, however ideally I would like to have these written with a loop and then saved to the environment if possible.

Comment: `sapply()` *is* a loop.  And you can just assign the result.  Why make it harder than it has to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can do this quickly and easily, in one line, with `sapply()`.

```
m1 <- t(sapply(LETTERS[1:8], paste0, 1:12, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
```

But you want to use a `for()` loop. So for that you can create an empty character matrix with desired dimensions first, then assign the rows in the loop.

```
m2 <- matrix("", 8, 12)
for(i in 1:8) {
    m2[i, ] <- paste0(LETTERS[i], 1:12)
}

identical(m1, m2)
# [1] TRUE
```

`m1` and `m2` are the following matrix:

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
> [1,] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5" "A6" "A7" "A8" "A9" "A10" "A11" "A12"
> [2,] "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" "B7" "B8" "B9" "B10" "B11" "B12"
> [3,] "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" "C5" "C6" "C7" "C8" "C9" "C10" "C11" "C12"
> [4,] "D1" "D2" "D3" "D4" "D5" "D6" "D7" "D8" "D9" "D10" "D11" "D12"
> [5,] "E1" "E2" "E3" "E4" "E5" "E6" "E7" "E8" "E9" "E10" "E11" "E12"
> [6,] "F1" "F2" "F3" "F4" "F5" "F6" "F7" "F8" "F9" "F10" "F11" "F12"
> [7,] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" "G5" "G6" "G7" "G8" "G9" "G10" "G11" "G12"
> [8,] "H1" "H2" "H3" "H4" "H5" "H6" "H7" "H8" "H9" "H10" "H11" "H12"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `outer` function:

```
nameMatrix <- outer(LETTERS[1:8], 1:12, paste, sep = "")
nameMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5" "A6" "A7" "A8" "A9" "A10" "A11" "A12"
[2,] "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" "B7" "B8" "B9" "B10" "B11" "B12"
[3,] "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" "C5" "C6" "C7" "C8" "C9" "C10" "C11" "C12"
[4,] "D1" "D2" "D3" "D4" "D5" "D6" "D7" "D8" "D9" "D10" "D11" "D12"
[5,] "E1" "E2" "E3" "E4" "E5" "E6" "E7" "E8" "E9" "E10" "E11" "E12"
[6,] "F1" "F2" "F3" "F4" "F5" "F6" "F7" "F8" "F9" "F10" "F11" "F12"
[7,] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" "G5" "G6" "G7" "G8" "G9" "G10" "G11" "G12"
[8,] "H1" "H2" "H3" "H4" "H5" "H6" "H7" "H8" "H9" "H10" "H11" "H12"
```

If you want to further assign them as some variable name, you can create a list:

```
li <- setNames(vector("list", 96), nameMatrix)
head(li)
$A1
NULL

$B1
NULL

$C1
NULL

$D1
NULL

$E1
NULL

$F1
NULL
```

And you can access these variables as `li$A1`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df <- expand.grid(LETTERS[1:8], 1:12)
v <- paste0(df[[1]], df[[2]])
m <- matrix(v, 8, 12)

> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5" "A6" "A7" "A8" "A9" "A10" "A11" "A12"
[2,] "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" "B7" "B8" "B9" "B10" "B11" "B12"
[3,] "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" "C5" "C6" "C7" "C8" "C9" "C10" "C11" "C12"
[4,] "D1" "D2" "D3" "D4" "D5" "D6" "D7" "D8" "D9" "D10" "D11" "D12"
[5,] "E1" "E2" "E3" "E4" "E5" "E6" "E7" "E8" "E9" "E10" "E11" "E12"
[6,] "F1" "F2" "F3" "F4" "F5" "F6" "F7" "F8" "F9" "F10" "F11" "F12"
[7,] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" "G5" "G6" "G7" "G8" "G9" "G10" "G11" "G12"
[8,] "H1" "H2" "H3" "H4" "H5" "H6" "H7" "H8" "H9" "H10" "H11" "H12"
```